# Pre-allocating drive space for file storage

Tags: java, database, vfs

Is there a Java way to pre-allocate drive space for exclusive usage in the application?

There is no requirement for this space to be a separate filesystem or a part of existing filesystem (so could easily be a database), but it should allow for reserving the specified amount of space and allow for random reads/writes with high enough throughput.

Comment: Wnat do you mean with pre-allocate? To make sure that a certain amout of space is available or a certain adresses available?

Comment: I want to reserve N GB for my application so that no other application or the OS can write there. I think pre-allocating a big enough file would work, but I hope there are better approaches like a DB/VFS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using a RandomAccessFile object and use the setLength() method.

Example:

```
File file = ... //Create a temporary file on the filesystem your trying to reserve.
long bytes = ... //number of bytes you want to reserve.

RandomAccessFile rf = null;
try{
    rf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw"); //rw stands for open in read/write mode.
    rf.setLength(bytes); //This will cause java to "reserve" memory for your application by inflating/truncating the file to the specific size.

    //Do whatever you want with the space here...
}catch(IOException ex){
    //Handle this...
}finally{
    if(rf != null){
        try{
            rf.close(); //Lets be nice and tidy here.
        }catch(IOException ioex){
            //Handle this if you want...
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The file must exist before you create the RandomAccessFile object.

The RandomAccessFile object can then be used to read/write to the file. Make sure the target filesystem has enough free space. The space may not be "exclusive" per-say but you can always use File Locks to do that.

P.S: If you end up realizing hard drives are slow and useless (or meant to use RAM from the start) you can use the ByteBuffer object from java.nio. The allocate() and allocateDirect() methods should be more than enough. The byte buffer will be allocated into RAM (and possible SwapFile) and will be exclusive to this java program. Random access can be done by changing the position of the buffer. Since these buffers use signed integers to reference position, max sizes are limited to 2^31 - 1.

Read more on RandomAccessFile [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Read more on FileLock (the java object) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).

Read more on ByteBuffer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Comment: `setLength` won't actually allocate storage for the file on most production file systems, such as ext4 and xfs, which use sparse files by default. The `fallocate` answer is the most correct. However, its primary benefits are durability (no need to sync/flush block allocation metadata) and reliability (no SIGBUS on a memory-mapped file due to a full disk); performance may not actually be much different.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson Thanks, I didn't know. Looking at OpenJDK sources it seems that linux variants are managed via `lseek()` so you're probably right in that aspect. Though using `fallocate()` would probably JNI work if used from java.

Comment: `setLength` calls `ftruncate` (via the `JVM_SetLength` primitive) to actually set the length on POSIX systems (`lseek` is used just to move the file pointer). `ftruncate` doesn't preallocate, which is why `fallocate` is necessary (but is used nowhere in the JDK). I'll include a JNA-based answer here.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson Apologies, I read the source for `length` instead of `setLength` and determined that `lseek` was the only functional call it was making. My point still standards in that there is no java-only way to do it (though your JNA-based answer seems like it could work). I'd be interested to see it when you are done.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a stripped down version of my JNA-based `fallocate` solution. The main trick is obtaining the native file descriptor. I've only tested it on Linux so far, but it should work on all modern POSIX/non-Windows systems. It's not necessary on Windows, as Windows does not create sparse files by default (only with `StandardOpenOption.SPARSE`), so `RandomAccessFile.setLength(size)` or `FileChannel.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(1), size - 1)` are adequate there.

```
/**
 * Provides access to operating system-specific {@code fallocate} and
 * {@code posix_fallocate} functions.
 */
public final class Fallocate {

    private static final boolean IS_LINUX = Platform.isLinux();
    private static final boolean IS_POSIX = !Platform.isWindows();

    private static final int FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE = 0x01;

    private final int fd;
    private int mode;
    private long offset;
    private final long length;

    private Fallocate(int fd, long length) {
        if (!isSupported()) {
            throwUnsupported("fallocate");
        }
        this.fd = fd;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public static boolean isSupported() {
        return IS_POSIX;
    }

    public static Fallocate forChannel(FileChannel channel, long length) {
        return new Fallocate(getDescriptor(channel), length);
    }

    public static Fallocate forDescriptor(FileDescriptor descriptor, long length) {
        return new Fallocate(getDescriptor(descriptor), length);
    }

    public Fallocate fromOffset(long offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
        return this;
    }

    public Fallocate keepSize() {
        requireLinux("fallocate keep size");
        mode |= FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE;
        return this;
    }

    private void requireLinux(String feature) {
        if (!IS_LINUX) {
            throwUnsupported(feature);
        }
    }

    private void throwUnsupported(String feature) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(feature +
                " is not supported on this operating system");
    }

    public void execute() throws IOException {
        final int errno;
        if (IS_LINUX) {
            final int result = FallocateHolder.fallocate(fd, mode, offset, length);
            errno = result == 0 ? 0 : Native.getLastError();
        } else {
            errno = PosixFallocateHolder.posix_fallocate(fd, offset, length);
        }
        if (errno != 0) {
            throw new IOException("fallocate returned " + errno);
        }
    }

    private static class FallocateHolder {

        static {
            Native.register(Platform.C_LIBRARY_NAME);
        }

        private static native int fallocate(int fd, int mode, long offset, long length);
    }

    private static class PosixFallocateHolder {

        static {
            Native.register(Platform.C_LIBRARY_NAME);
        }

        private static native int posix_fallocate(int fd, long offset, long length);
    }

    private static int getDescriptor(FileChannel channel) {
        try {
            // sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl declares private final java.io.FileDescriptor fd
            final Field field = channel.getClass().getDeclaredField("fd");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return getDescriptor((FileDescriptor) field.get(channel));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported FileChannel implementation", e);
        }
    }

    private static int getDescriptor(FileDescriptor descriptor) {
        try {
            // Oracle java.io.FileDescriptor declares private int fd
            final Field field = descriptor.getClass().getDeclaredField("fd");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return (int) field.get(descriptor);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported FileDescriptor implementation", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using reflection to get the fd you could: `jdk.internal.access.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().get(descriptor);`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems you can use fallocate() system call. It's extremely fast. Just run Bash command.

**UPD:**

`fallocate -l 10G 10Gigfile`

Answer (score -5):

You can pre-allocate space by writing a large file,  but to be honest I wouldn't bother. Performance will be pretty good/ probably better than you need.

If you really needed performance, you'd be writing C++/C# and doing RAW I/O.

But that's typically only done when writing an RDBMS engine, high-volume media capture or similar.

Comment: Java isn't much slower than C++ so I wouldn't bother choosing between the languages by performance

Comment: Yes, Java performs similarly to C++. But typically it's used for high-level & business work -- above the OS -- rather than bare-metal stuff. Because the JVM is an abstraction, you don't typically have close & fast access to high-volume APIs such as raw disk, media capture etc.

Comment: -1 _Don't bother_ isn't really an answer. R/W performance may not be important, but having reserved space for a file to be populated later is. Plus if we're talking about spin drives, having all chunks next to each other  as opposed to all over the place can and does improve performance significantly, esp. for large files (I know this is an old answer but still...)